# Mac mini 2018 cursor freezes after RAM upgrade

Tags: usb, memory, mouse, mac-mini, cursor

My Mac mini 2018 (3 GHz  Core i5) runs Mojave 10.14.6. Monitor is an LG UHD 27UK850.

After a RAM upgrade to 32GB the cursor regularly but momentarily freezes approximately every 4 seconds - a major annoyance with photo editing!

I use a wired non-Apple mouse, but the same thing happens with a Magic Mouse 2 and a Logitech wireless mouse and another non-Apple mouse. Note that other than to test with the Magic Mouse, I have Bluetooth turned off.

After trying various solutions, like Safe Boot; resetting NVPAM ; removing mouse-related plist items in ~/Library/Preferences, by process of elimination I found that 2 of the 3 USB-C hubs I use (USB-C to 3 x USB 3.0) seem to be causing the problem.

The problem-causing hubs are unbranded, but have been working perfectly, and they do not cause any issue at all on a 2017 MacBook Pro.

System info for the problem (unbranded) hubs (USB-C to USB-C + 3 x USB 3.0) is: Product ID:0x0612, Vendor ID:   0x05e3  (Genesys Logic, Inc.), Version: 92.26, Speed:Up to 5 Gb/sec, Manufacturer:  GenesysLogic.

This is identical to the System info for the NON problem "Aero cool" hub (USB-C to Ethernet + 3 x USB 3.0).

But on the Mac mini, even with no peripheral devices connected to these hubs, the cursor freezes momentarily approx. every 4 seconds. Remove the hubs and all is fine.

The other hub, an Aerocool, did cause Bluetooth interference on the MacBook Pro until I wrapped its lead in foil, but still works fine on the Mac mini and doesn't affect the cursor.

I am stumped as to why more RAM appears to have created this issue as previously my cursor never froze and the hubs themselves cause no issues on another Mac.

```
default 10:40:48.665165 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [EDID] Not display connected to Port.. Bail out
default 10:40:50.172541 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Port enable
default 10:40:50.172562 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] Port Enable for fb1 with state=0
default 10:40:51.320424 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] FB1 port = 2 at 10593802368
default 10:40:51.320454 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] fb->fDPCDParams.SinkCount = 0
default 10:40:51.320475 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] HPD is high
default 10:40:51.320479 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] FB1 Setting DP power state = 1
default 10:40:51.475880 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] Set DP power state failed. Returned state 0
default 10:40:51.475887 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] Setting DP power failed (0xe00002bc), ignoring empty dongle handling (likely HDMI/TMDS case)
default 10:40:51.475889 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] isHPDLow = 0 emptyDongle = 0 sinkCount = 0 sinkCountChanged = 0
default 10:40:51.555904 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] Event insert
default 10:40:51.555920 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] Hotplug - disable RC
default 10:40:51.555922 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] FB1: Hot plug on port2
default 10:40:51.555923 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] Clear EDID cache flags flags=0
default 10:40:51.555926 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] AGDC managing Display: Start listening to AGDC
default 10:40:51.555928 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] FB1 port = 2 at 10594037883
default 10:40:51.555928 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] fb->fDPCDParams.SinkCount = 0
default 10:40:51.558613 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] HPD is low
default 10:40:51.558617 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] isHPDLow = 1 emptyDongle = 0 sinkCount = 0 sinkCountChanged = 0
default 10:40:51.640157 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] Event remove
default 10:40:51.640164 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] Unplug - enabling RC
default 10:40:51.640167 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] FB1: Display unplugged from port2
default 10:40:51.640168 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] Clear EDID cache flags flags=0
default 10:40:51.640171 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] AGDC managing Display: Start listening to AGDC
default 10:40:51.640505 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Get stream AUX access
default 10:40:51.655200 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Get stream AUX access
default 10:40:51.670419 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Get stream AUX access
default 10:40:51.718605 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Get stream AUX access
default 10:40:51.766602 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Get stream AUX access
default 10:40:51.806827 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Port enable
default 10:40:51.806835 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] Port Enable for fb1 with state=1
default 10:40:51.806854 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Get stream AUX access
default 10:40:51.819926 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Get stream AUX access
default 10:40:51.830378 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Get stream AUX access
default 10:40:51.843406 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Get stream AUX access
default 10:40:51.854357 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Get stream AUX access
default 10:40:51.867515 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Get stream AUX access
default 10:40:51.878447 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Get stream AUX access
default 10:40:51.890803 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Get stream AUX access
default 10:40:51.901136 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Get stream AUX access
default 10:40:51.915422 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Get stream AUX access
default 10:40:51.926372 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Get EDID
default 10:40:51.926381 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [EDID] DisplayPath = 0 port = 2
default 10:40:51.926382 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [EDID] Matched
default 10:40:51.929131 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [EDID] Not display connected to Port.. Bail out
default 10:40:58.459824 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [EDID] DisplayPath = 0 port = 2
default 10:40:58.459827 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [EDID] Matched
default 10:40:58.462654 +1100   kernel  [IGFB][INFO   ] [EDID] Not display connected to Port.. Bail out
```

Comment: Have you removed the extra ram and re-tested? To be sure? Have the hubs done a self-update lately?

Comment: If you have odd problems you didn't have before a hardware upgrade, it is likely caused by the hardware upgrade no matter how unrelated it may seem. If you remove the RAM and the problem goes away, replace the RAM.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but as everything else is working perfectly, and given that others have had similar unexplained issues with USB-C devices affecting cursor behaviour, I'll leave things be.

Comment: It may be that the RAM just needs reseating: take it out and put it in again. It's possible that the pointer issues are the only problems you're seeing, but there may be others that are transparent to the user. I've installed 32 Gb in the same Mini (2018, i5), and I had to take it apart again to make sure the RAM was seated correctly.

Comment: I looked at the console and found the following section was being repeated only when the USB Hub was plugged in. I'm not sure how to interpret this log but it looks like the Mac is expecting a display.

Comment: I can't add the full log sequence (too long) but it has to do with the graphics frame buffer                                                          default 10:40:48.665165 +1100 kernel [IGFB][INFO   ] [EDID] Not display connected to Port.. Bail out
default 10:40:50.172541 +1100 kernel [IGFB][INFO   ] [AGDC] Port enable
default 10:40:50.172562 +1100 kernel [IGFB][INFO   ] Port Enable for fb1 with state=0
default 10:40:51.320424 +1100 kernel [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] FB1 port = 2 at 10593802368
default 10:40:51.320454 +1100 kernel [IGFB][INFO   ] [Hot_Plug] fb->fDPCDParams.SinkCount = 0

Comment: Added console log for the repeating section to the original question. Note that this sequence or anything remotely like it does not occur with the non-problematic hub.

Comment: @solarmike: as it happens I did not seat the memory properly at first and the mini would not boot; the second time I made sure they were properly seated.

Comment: A useful test would be to see if you can find a hub that does not cause this problem, or if all (known) USB hubs cause it.

Comment: Thanks @benwiggy but as I mentioned in OP a third hub causes no issues (even though its manufacturer and model ID is identical with the problem ones). I have since also tried a DELL hub which didn't cause any issues.